# Stuck with a regex to exclude optional items

Tags: regex

I am using an application that allows the use of a regex to control the naming of entities.

I have a bunch of entities named like this (each line is the whole name):

```
Subsystem - CPU - Utilisation [1x]
Subsystem - CPU - Utilisation [2x]
Subsystem - CPU - Utilisation [4x]
Subsystem - CPU - Queue Length
Subsystem - Disk - Space
Subsystem - Disk - Capacity
```

And I need to use the regex to turn each one into this:

```
CPU \n Utilisation
CPU \n Queue Length
Disk \n Space
Disk \n Capacity
```

(the spaces around the `\n` are for clarity, and not in the real output)

The regex I'm using for that is:

```
Find:     ^Subsystem - (.*) - (.*)( \[.*\])$
Replace:  ${1}\n${2}
```

Which works for the ones with a `[something]` part, but not those without.

Essentially, I need to get `part1` and `part2`, where `part2` is terminated either by `[` or the end of the line.

Comment: What I don't understand is what do you want to do with [1x] for example, because it shows nowhere on your expected output. If you're just going to ignore them, no need to add it in the regex.

Comment: I need to exclude them. If I leave it out entirely, then {2} will contain the [part].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This regex should get you the matches:</strike>

```
^Subsystem - ([^\s-]+) - ([^\s\[]+)(?=(?:\s\[)|$).*$
```

Tested at this [Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/4OwEOzrN4b)

**Edit:**
Updated to include "Queue Length"

```
^Subsystem - ([^\s-]+) - (.+?)(?=(?:\s+\[)|$).*$
```

Tested at this [Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/BnjgKrsi8x)

Breakdown:

- `^Subsystem -` :self explanatory, matching the first few constant chars
- `([^\s-]+)` :capturing group of a negative charset, basically that matches anything until it hits a space or a hyphen
- `(.+?)(?=(?:\s+\[)|$)` :Positive lookahead to match anything (non-greedily) that is always followed by EITHER spaces and "[" OR  end of line. The `?:` is a non-capturing group so that it does not match it.
- `.*$` :match anything else until end of line

Comment: Almost! It's missing the "Queue Length" item, seemingly because of the space in the phrase.

Comment: Legendary. Thank you. Might take me a while to work out what it's doing, but it works!

Comment: Such useless complications actually :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Do you have a less uselessly complicated solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (make the last part optional - zero or once):

```
^Subsystem - (.*) - (.*)( \[.*\])?$
```

That should work!

Also, I love using http://rubular.com/ to try out my regexps.

Comment: Good tip with Rubular, not seen that before. Your regex doesn't work with my input and output though.

Comment: this includes the `[...]` in the matches. Morever you need to make the last group a non-capturing one.

Comment: Thanks guys! I had just tested it quickly on rubular and it seemed to work, but @Kash, your answer is far superior, good Sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on Notepad++)

```
.+?- +([\w ]+) +- +([\w ]+) .*
```

Explanation:

`.+?-` non-greedy until first dash -

`+([\w ]+) +` - second word (only letters and spaces) match between 1 or more spaces

`- +([\w ]+)` - second word (only letters and spaces) match preceded by dash and one or more spaces

`.*` - the rest of the string

Comment: this regex would exclude "Length" because `\w` does not include space.

Comment: That's excluding anything that doesn't have a [] element.

Answer (score -1):

Then you can just make the [...] part optional :

```
^Subsystem - (.*) - (.*?)(?: \[.*\])?$
```

Comment: I still get the [part] in my results.

Comment: this includes the [...] in the matches. Morever you need to make the last group a non-capturing one. Your `*` is greedy

Answer (score -1):

Just need another * before the $ sign.
Use as below:
    `^Subsystem - (.*) - (.*)( \[.*\])*$`